# How to start a processing time timer in CustomTrigger only on the first element?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using GlobalWindow with custom `Trigger` for my application. As per the requirement, in the Trigger function, I need to start a processing time timer only on the first element in the window.

I tried implementing it using a variable `firstEventflag`. Like so.

```
.window(GlobalWindows.create())
.trigger(new Trigger<ImpactEventObject, GlobalWindow>() {
    Boolean firstEventflag = false;

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onElement(ImpactEventObject impactEventObject, long l, GlobalWindow globalWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
        if (!firstEventflag) {
            firstEventflag = true;
            triggerContext.registerProcessingTimeTimer(
                triggerContext.getCurrentProcessingTime() + 20000);
        }
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long l, GlobalWindow globalWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
    return TriggerResult.FIRE;
}
```

But this fails because today I discovered that the variable `firstEventflag` is not initialized every time a new window is created, it depends on the subtask that is processing the window, meaning different windows can share the same variable `firstEventflag` rendering this logic effectively useless. Given this, how do I go about solving my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out a way of doing this by looking at the source code of `CountTrigger` [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/triggers/CountTrigger.java).

We can keep the count of number of elements in the `GlobalWindow` with a `ReducingStateDescriptor`. And start the timer when this count is 1, meaning - start the timer only on the first element.

```
public class CustomTrigger extends Trigger<GenericObject, GlobalWindow> {

private final ReducingStateDescriptor<Long> stateDesc = new ReducingStateDescriptor<>("count", new Sum(), LongSerializer.INSTANCE);

@Override
public TriggerResult onElement(ImpactEventObject impactEventObject, long l, GlobalWindow globalWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
    ReducingState<Long> count = triggerContext.getPartitionedState(stateDesc);
    count.add(1L);

    if (count.get() == 1) {
        triggerContext.registerProcessingTimeTimer(
            triggerContext.getCurrentProcessingTime() + 20000);
    }
    return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
}

@Override
public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long l, GlobalWindow globalWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
    return TriggerResult.FIRE;
}

@Override
public TriggerResult onEventTime(long l, GlobalWindow globalWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void clear(GlobalWindow globalWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
    triggerContext.deleteProcessingTimeTimer(triggerContext.getCurrentProcessingTime());
}

private static class Sum implements ReduceFunction<Long> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public Long reduce(Long value1, Long value2) throws Exception {
        return value1 + value2;
    }

}
}
```